# Background image not appearing in IE8

Tags: css, image, internet-explorer-8, background

I have a background image that I'm trying to use as a logo. All's fine in Chrome & FF, but it's not showing in IE8. The background images simply don't load. How can I get them to show in IE8?

this is the code:

```
<header>
    <h1 class="logo">
        <a href="http://publix.newhaven.edu/hlee-test">Henry C. Lee Institute of Forensic Science</a>
    </h1>    
</header>
```

css:

```
header {
    margin: 0 10px 38px 7px; 
    padding: 30px 0 0 0;
}
header h1{
    width:232px;
}
header h1 a {
    background:url('images/logo.png') 0 0 no-repeat; 
    display:block;
    height:89px;
    text-decoration:none; 
    text-indent:-9999px;
    width:243px;
}
```

Comment: Do you use html5shiv.js ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add in `head` of your page next:

```
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
<script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
```

In css you need write default styles for new html5 tags:

```
header, footer, section, nav, article {
    display: block;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

html5shiv.js - create new html5 tags in DOM. Old browsers like IE8 don't know about html5 tags.

https://code.google.com/p/html5shiv/

Answer (score 0):

Your

```
header h1 a {
   ....
}
```

needs a `line-height`.

Answer (score 0):

give proper float property. it's affecting it.